# Adding the :focus pseudo-class in a select element and <input> elements with type="file"

Tags: html, css, forms, tags

As a beginner I found this really helpful and I still want to learn more. Can you help me with some tutorial on how to apply **Adding the :focus pseudo-class** in a `select element` change somehow the border-bottom color **after choosing** an option to its dropdown? I mean `:focus` work and visible while selecting but how about leaving it with a content? Thanks!

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600&display=swap');
*{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
form .fields .input-field {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.input-field input, select{
    outline: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #333;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0 15px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 2px solid transparent;
    height: 42px;
    margin: 8px 0;
}
.input-field input:is(:focus, :valid){
    border-bottom-color: #4070f4;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <div class="fields">
    <div class="input-field">
      <label>Student ID</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your ID" required>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field">
      <label>Section</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your section" 
      required>
    </div>
    
    <div class="input-field">
      <label>Department</label>
      <select required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select department
        </option>
        <option value="jhs">JHS Department</option>
        <option value="shs">SHS Department</option>
        <option value="college">College/TED Department</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This is my first time asking a question sorry for that. I want to style the form inputs select element. After choosing an option to the select element the border color should be same as the input text when you type or inserted something.

Comment: Your css does not have a `select`  selector for `:focus`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the selector `.input-field select:valid` to target the select element too.

```css
.input-field input:is(:focus, :valid),
.input-field select:valid
{
  border-bottom-color: #4070f4;
}
```

Comment: I dont know how to thank you for the feedback but this works. Much love!

Comment: You can use the checkmark on the left to mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate class for the select element, then you can add a psudeo class or something else

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600&display=swap');
*{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
form .fields .input-field {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.input-field input, select{
    outline: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #333;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0 15px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 2px solid transparent;
    height: 42px;
    margin: 8px 0;
}
.input-field input:is(:focus, :valid){
    border-bottom-color: aqua;
}

.select:focus{
    border-bottom-color: aqua;
}

.select:valid{
    border-bottom-color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <div class="fields">
    <div class="input-field">
      <label>Student ID</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your ID" required>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field">
      <label>Section</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your section" 
      required>
    </div>
    
    <div class="input-field">
      <label>Department</label>
      <select required class="select">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select department
        </option>
        <option value="jhs">JHS Department</option>
        <option value="shs">SHS Department</option>
        <option value="college">College/TED Department</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I dont know how to thank you for the feedback but this works. Much love!

Comment: you can vote up or accept this answer